# Knockout - Is there a better approach to my binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Some advice please I have setup a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/cagnL1o1/6/

```
    var data = [{ PostCodeStart: "", PostCodeEnd: "", Mileage: "", Notes: "" }];//[{ PostCodeStart: "PO200QW", PostCodeEnd: "SE1 9FD", Mileage: "127", Notes:"Hello World" }];

    var viewModel = {
        journeyList: ko.observableArray(data),
        journeyListNotBound: [],
        add: function (data) {
            if (data.PostCodeStart === "" || data.PostCodeEnd === "" || data.Mileage === "") {
                alert("empty field");
            }
            else {
//Do I need this journeyListNotBound
                viewModel.journeyListNotBound.push({ PostCodeStart: data.PostCodeStart, PostCodeEnd: data.PostCodeEnd, Mileage: data.Mileage, Notes: data.Notes });
                viewModel.journeyList.push({ PostCodeStart: postCodeStart, PostCodeEnd: postCodeEnd, Mileage: mileage, Notes: notes });
            }
        },

        remove: function (data) {
            viewModel.journeyList.remove(data);
        }
    };
```

Now, each time the user presses the + button I would like to have Start Post code, End Post code, and Mileage and notes all start with an empty string.  I have achieved this( with the help of ROY ) but with the use of a normal Javascript array ( journeyListNotBound ) so we have a KO array and Javascript array is there no way we can do this with only a KO array ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking - `journeyListNotBound` doesn't appear to be used anywhere.  You can comment out `journeyListNotBound: [],` and `viewModel.journeyListNotBound.push(...` with no ill effects?

Comment: change journeyListNotBound: [] to journeyListNotBound: ko.observableArray([])

Comment: Hi  if you comment out viewModel.journeyListNotBound the PostCodeStart values are not being stored in the KO array as we are pushing "" onto the array.

Comment: That's just the default value for the new element at the end of the array - all the other elements in the array should still have the values bound from the text boxes.

Comment: Actually, looking at your jsfiddle, it looks like you're repeating in the wrong place.  Do you want to display the information in the table at the top, and then only have 1 set of textboxes that add new information?

Comment: Hi James,  yes that is what I would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if http://jsfiddle.net/kjv07wrg/ is more like you wanted.

I made a custom class `JourneyStep` and assigned an object with empty properties for each new step. Also, the `viewModel` which now is a function was called with `new viewModel()`. I changed the Plus button to appear only once in the UI, and every step kept its remove button.

Comment: Nicely done, but a question: it looks like a JourneyStep is exactly the same as what is passed in to initialize it. Why not just pass the object literal?

Comment: @RoyJ if you need to observe specific properties of the custom class that is a good convention I think, but more experience ko developers must probably use the mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and do as you say :P